# Error while composing a docker image

Tags: docker, docker-compose

While running docker-compose up i am getting following error message ? Can anyone suggest what can be the cause?

> "ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:   postgresql-dev-9.6.2-r0:
>       breaks: world[postgresql-dev=9.5.4-r0]"

I have also tried to install postgresql both versions and below is the ouput:

> "pip install postgresql-dev-9.6.2-r0 Collecting
>   postgresql-dev-9.6.2-r0   Could not find a version that satisfies the
>   requirement postgresql-dev-9.6.2-r0 (from versions: ) No matching
>   distribution found for postgresql-dev-9.6.2-r0"
>
> "pip install postgresql-dev-9.5.4-r0 Collecting
>   postgresql-dev-9.5.4-r0   Could not find a version that satisfies the
>   requirement postgresql-dev-9.5.4-r0 (from versions: ) No matching
>   distribution found for postgresql-dev-9.5.4-r0"

Comment: this looks like a pip or postgresql issue rather than a docker issue (unless you tell me it only fails in a docker container)

Comment: I think you are right, with pip installation directly on terminal its failing too 
>$ pip install postgresql-dev-9.6.2-r0
>Collecting postgresql-dev-9.6.2-r0
> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement postgresql-dev->9.6.2-r0 (from versions: )
>No matching distribution found for postgresql-dev-9.6.2-r0
>You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
>You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: Post your `Dockerfile`. That's an `apk` error, maybe you are specifying a specific version to install? 9.5.4 is the package currently available to the alpine version you are using.

Comment: [packages](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=postgresql&branch=&repo=&arch=&maintainer=) 3.4 is on 9.5.6 and 3.5 is on 9.6.2

Comment: ERROR: Service 'XXX-data' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apk add --update     python    py2-pip    python-dev    git    gcc    musl-dev    libffi-dev    libjpeg-turbo-dev    zlib    zlib-dev    bash && apk add postgresql-dev==9.5.4-r0 --update-cache     --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.4/main/  && pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt && apk del    git    gcc    python3-dev    musl-dev    libffi-dev && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*' returned a non-zero code: 1